# Cursores con SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

llevo un curso de t-sql y en la clase hicimos esto , pero mi profesor nos dijo que tratáramos con esto insertar datos  usando cursores , ya intente todo , pero no me sale
El punto es que insertáramos mas de 500 registros en alumnos y fechas con valor de "F" O "P".Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
go
declare @cod varchar(50)
declare @lista varchar(max)

declare cursor1 cursor 

for select Codigo from Alumno
open cursor1
fetch cursor1 into @cod
set @lista=''

 while(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
 begin
 set @lista+=@cod +', '

 fetch cursor1 into @cod

 end

print @lista

close cursor1

deallocate cursor1

 select Codigo from Alumno
 -------------- 

declare @fecha date
declare @fechanueva date
declare @i int
set @fecha=GETDATE()
set @i=0
while (@i<=30)
begin
set @i+=1
set @fecha=(select DATEADD(day,2,@fecha))
print @fecha`introducir el código aquí`

end
 select floor(rand()*(3-1)+1) as tabla
```

Comment: Necesariamente debe ser con cursores ?

Comment: Los cursores son un pésimo recurso para estos casos. Espero que eso lo mencione constantemente el profesor o sería bueno que alguien más lo hiciera. Un cursor necesita que ya existan los datos y será muy lento en el procesamiento. Con mucho gusto te puedo enseñar como hacerlo sin necesidad de cursores.

Comment: Podrías publicar el código de creación de las tablas? Ya tienes datos en la tabla `Alumno` y debes insertar en `Asistencia`?

Comment: @LuisCazares El tema es sobre cursores ,  y si tengo 18 alumnos registrador , pero tengo que insertar diferentes dias a estos alumnos , con fechas  y valor , como esta el codigo que puse

Answer (score 0):

No entendí mucho la lógica de fechas y valores, pero el siguiente ejemplo genera 500 registros por cada alumno, sumando fecha e insertando un valor random.

```
DECLARE @Alumno TABLE (Codigo int, Datos nvarchar(10))
DECLARE @T_asistencia TABLE (Cod_Asistencia int, Codigo_alum int, fecha date, valor int)
DECLARE @cod int,           --> codigo de alumno en el cursor
        @indice int,        --> utilizado para el bucle de insercion
        @cnt_registros int  --> cnt de registros por alumno

INSERT @Alumno VALUES (1,'F')
INSERT @Alumno VALUES (2,'P')
SET @indice = 1
SET @cnt_registros = 500

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT Codigo
FROM @Alumno

OPEN cursor1

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 
INTO @cod

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    WHILE @indice <= @cnt_registros 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @T_asistencia
        VALUES (@indice, @cod, DATEADD(DAY,@indice,GETDATE()), FLOOR(RAND() * 500))

        SET @indice = @indice + 1
    END

    SET @indice = 1 --> reiniciar indice para nuevo alumno

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 
    INTO @cod
END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1

SELECT 
    al.Codigo,
    al.Datos,
    asis.Cod_Asistencia,
    asis.fecha,
    asis.valor
FROM @T_asistencia asis
JOIN @Alumno al ON al.Codigo = asis.Codigo_alum
```